# How to integrate a Xloudia's Unity3D Xcode into an Objective C project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, augmented-reality

I want to integrate Xloudia Augmented reality in my iOS project. They don't have iOS sdk for integration but they are providing unity package for integration.

They told like that you have to export unity package and integrate it in your Xcode project.

I export unity project as a Xcode project. Now i have to add that project in my existing Xcode project. But i don't know how to add it.

Can any one please help me to integrate Xloudia in iOS?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am always interested in Vuforia/Unity and how to integrate it into an existing application.

Comment: @Packy No, still i don't know how to integrate unity Xcode project as a sub project in existing iOS project. If you find any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its not for vuforia but might help since it involves Unity into iOS

[Link](http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/08/06/add-unity3d-in-a-native-ios-application/)